# Batch File to Launch Chrome Extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, google-chrome-extension

I have the following in my bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome-extension://<<Chrome Extension ID>>/index.html#/inventory
```

This yields:

> Your file was not found  It may have been moved or deleted. 
>   ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I have tried on different computers with different Chrome extensions with identical results. Any ideas?

Comment: Its working in my system, add only  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" to batch file. Don't add chrome-extension.

Comment: @Mallikarjun That will only start up chrome. I want to open a specific extension after starting chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the Chrome browser, just go to "chrome://extensions/", click on "Details" for the extension you want to run. There's a button like "create link" (don't know what the english translation is exactly). A shortcut will be created on your desktop where you can see the exact code needed.

Comment: I only see the "Remove" button.